# error CS0103: The name 'UserContext' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net

I have inherited an ASP.Net 2.0 Web application built in VS 2005 and am trying to port it to VS 2017 and Framework 4.8.  In a class that is trying to determine if the user is authorized to access the system it is erroring with "error CS0103: The name 'UserContext' does not exist in the current context" and when I am in the debug mode and evaluating the line where the error is occurring the UserContext essentially does not know who the user is (me in this case) at all.  I assume that it is something wrong with the web.config file settings or something.  Am I missing something in the web.config file perhaps?  Do I need to change the use of the UserContext to something else for Framework 4.0?

```
using System;
using CoreServices; //CoreServices is a webservice


.... partial class code where authentication check is being called ....

public static void InitUserContext()
{
    if (UserContext.Current.Initialized)
        return;

    UserDTO user = null;
    CoreService proxy = new CoreService();

    DataContractUserDTO result = proxy.UserByLogin(UserContext.Current.GetLogin()); /// Code is erroring here

    if (!result.Success)
    {
        if (result.CriticalError)
            GotoErrorPage(result.ErrorMessage);

        user = new UserDTO();
        user.FullName = UserContext.Current.GetFullName();
        user.Login = UserContext.Current.GetLogin();

        DataContractOfFLRTUserDTO userResult = proxy.CreateUser(user);

        if (!userResult.Success)
        {
            if (userResult.CriticalError)
                GotoErrorPage(userResult.ErrorMessage);
        }

        user = userResult.Data[0];

    }
    else
        user = result.Data[0];

    string roles = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Roles) ? "" : user.Roles);

    UserContext.Current.InitContext(user.UserID.Value, user.FullName, roles);
}   

//***************************************************
    CoreServices method being called from above:
//***************************************************

[WebMethod(Description = "Find a user by login")]
public DataContract<UserDTO> UserByLogin(string login)
{
    try
    {
        App.Data.UserData data = new App.Data.UserData(database);
        UserDTO[] result = data.SearchBy(null, null, null, login, null);
        return new DataContract<UserDTO>(result);
    }
    catch (DataException de)
    {
        return new DataContract<UserDTO>(de.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new DataContract<UserDTO>(ex);
    }
}



//***************************************************    
    webConfig:
//***************************************************        

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="3000"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.OracleClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Drawing.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
</httpHandlers>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
</system.web>
<location allowOverride="true">
   <appSettings>
      <add key="CoreServices.CoreService" value="http://localhost:7777/App.WEBSERVICE/CoreService.asmx"/>
   </appSettings>
</location>
<system.net>
   <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="apptest@hotmail.com">
          <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
   </mailSettings>
</system.net>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you got an error "error CS0103: The name 'UserContext' does not exist in the current context" then that's a compilation error. Where is that class defined? What namespace is it in? What assembly is it in? Is that assembly referenced by your web application?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation this an issue much deeper in the solution with some flawed logic in the code.